# notepad++ find and replace regex

Tags: notepad++, replace

I have in txt file lines like this:

```
(1, 'Peach', '["8","9"]'),
...
(31, 'Apple', '["8","9"]'),
(32, 'Orange', '["8","0"]'),
(33, 'Mango', '["8","0"]'),
...
(344, 'Melon', '["8","9"]'),
```

and I want them **without numbers**. 
Like this:

```
('Peach', '["8","9"]'),
...
('Apple', '["8","9"]'),
('Orange', '["8","0"]'),
('Mango', '["8","0"]'),
...
('Melon', '["8","9"]'),
```

What regex "replace with..." I should use ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search for:

```
^\([0-9]+,\s*
```

replace with `\(`

Comment: this is working, but edit replace to phrase `\(`, and I will accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Find `\([0-9]+,\s*`

Replace `(`